# Blazor WASM PWA: Google Chrome does not show Push Notifications

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've just tested Blazor example [Blazing Pizza](https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop) that uses push notifications as a PWA feature on Blazor. I changed public/private keys with my own generated ones and ran the project with MS Edge browser and push notifications worked as desired. But when I open it with Google Chrome, it doesn't shows any notification! (I allowed to show notifications).
I traced `service-worker.js` and found that notification hits the breakpoint, it means notification receives by browser but not showing:
[image: Blazor service-worker.js debugging]
I checked my Chrome's settings but not found anything to change.

Answer (score 3):

I've found my mistake: I had blocked Google Chrome notifications in my Windows 10 notification settings!